# Differences in GPIO between Raspberry Pi 2 B and 3 B

Tags: gpio, pi-2, pi-3, rpi.gpio

Is there any difference in the GPIO layout between Raspberry Pi 2 B and 3 B? If yes, please provide the differences.

Comment: you might get some insight on looking into this. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/pinmappings/pinmappingsrpi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It basically depends on what aspect you are looking at.

The pins of all with 40pin headers (B+, Pi2, Pi3) are identical.

The functions which are allocated to the pins differ slightly. The Pi3 has a different UART assigned to the serial pins, and there is some difference in the 2nd I²C (which are normally reserved).

If you run `gpio readall` this will show current state. `gpio` SHOULD be installed, but was missing from some releases. It can be installed as part of `wiringpi` if missing.

Comment: All the pins should be the same numbers right? (BCM layout)

Comment: @human you can confirm that for yourself by running the gpio readall command millways mentioned