# GPIO Pin Reference Board For Raspberry Pi 3 model B

Tags: gpio, pi-3

I am looking for GPIO Pin Reference Board For **Raspberry Pi 3 model B**, but I cannot find any small board like the photo below. so, any help to find one as similar as possible?

**Note**: If there is a chinese shop it will be great.

[image]

Comment: Related (and thus probably a dupe) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/62471/19949

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GPIO port of the Pi 3 and the Pi 2 B and the Pi B+ are identical. So the linked reference board will work just fine.

Comment: Great. so, it's identical for the ALL 40 pins? and thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, all 40 pins are identical on the Pi Zero, A+, B+, 2B, and 3B.