# Connecting Hifiberry Digi+ clone (PiFi Digi+ V1.0) to an Raspberry Pi 1 B (26Pin Header)

Tags: gpio, audio, pi-1, hifiberry

Hi I wanted to make use of an older Raspberry Pi and build an Volumio Music Player. I ordered [Hifiberry Digi+ clone (PiFi Digi+ V1.0)](https://www.fasttech.com/products/1/10023729/5137000-pifi-hifi-digi-digital-sound-card-w-i2s-to-s-pdif), unfortunately I forgot I own an older Raspberry Pi 1 B with the 26PIN interface and unpopulated P5 header.

There are actually versions of this board on the market suited for Raspberry Pi 1, but before I order more electronic junk I wonder, whether there is a possibility to connect the board using the P5 header.

Hifiberry states:

> GPIOs 18-21 (pins 12, 35, 38 and 40) are used for the sound interface. You can’t use them for any other purpose.

I already found an topic describing the [inverted issue: 26PIN header board and Raspberry Pi 2](https://volumio.org/forum/hifiberry-digi-and-raspberry-t3878.html)

Are the first 26 header pins actually compatible between Raspberry Pi 1 and 2 ? If so, I would only need to connect pins pins 12, 35, 38 and 40 on the card to the P5 header.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think this is related (if not dupe): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/76300/19949 and note that the Pi Zero that question addresses has the same 40 pin header as all other newer Pis too.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, and as you already have the card you could try if it physically fits.

**However** there are NO "extension" cables available and making a 26 pin M-F cable is not feasible (due to lack of parts). You would need to make an adapter board.

You could use a a stacker header as an adapter.

I have done something similar (connecting a Gertboard to 40 pin Pi) by soldering a right-angle connector on top. This is tricky soldering, and you have to be aware of the crossed connections.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=76280&p=544846#p544846 and https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=324528

Personally I would just buy a newer Pi!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still trying to figure out the right pinout. I am even not sure about the right pinout of the audio card. It would but be just fine to connect the card and the RPi with cables.